# How to control error output format in Vim quickfix?

Tags: vim, pylint

I took this script - http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=891 - and modified it to show error numbers (e.g. not just `C` or `R`, but `C0301` or `R0202`) by adding `--include-ids\ y` to the command line invoking pylint and changing errorformat line from

```
CompilerSet efm=%+P[%f],%t:\ %#%l:%m,%Z,%+IYour\ code%m,%Z,%-G%.%#
```

to

```
CompilerSet efm=%+P[%f],%t%n:\ %#%l:%m,%Z,%+IYour\ code%m,%Z,%-G%.%#
```

Straightforward enough. But in the error output i get `C 301` instead of `C0301`. It is a minor issue, but still, i am puzzled - there seems to be no way of displaying this kind of error tags correctly. Am i missing something here?

While writing, i also noticed that it changes `E` error codes to `error` and `W` to `warning`. How can i control output format for `:clist` in general? Is it hardcoded?

Answer (score 0):

It is not hardcoded, it can be customized using 'errorformat' option.

Comment: 'errorformat' option controls *input* format, not *output* shown by `:clist`. By the way, `efm` used in question is a shortcut name for this option.